# pandas remove for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have now the following for loop which I want to get rid off, since it's too slow.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i,"date_time"] = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(df.loc[i,"Date"] + ' ' + df.loc[i,"Time"]), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Input:

```
index. date        time 
1      10-10-2010  00:00:00
2      10-10-2010  00:00:03
3      10-10-2010  00:00:06
4      10-10-2010  00:00:09
```

Desired output, with one column with datetime objects:

```
index. date        time      date_time
1      10-10-2010  00:00:00  10-10-2010  00:00:00
2      10-10-2010  00:00:03  10-10-2010  00:00:00
3      10-10-2010  00:00:06  10-10-2010  00:00:00
4      10-10-2010  00:00:09  10-10-2010  00:00:00
```

Comment: Please share a sample input with expected output.

Comment: You could use `df['Date'].apply()`. And then have the conversion function inside the apply.  You can check the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: @AnuragReddy, `.apply()` still iterates over the rows, so it would be equally slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever possible, use vector operations instead of loops. Something like this should work (tested on the included sample):

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
```